# Chrome Extension Issue in UiPath Robot Only

Tags: uipath, uipath-robot

I am facing the chrome extension issue. The following is the issue:
“UiPath.Core.BrowserOperationException: Cannot communicate with the browser, please check the UiPath extension”

I have UiPath Robot only so I cannot install extension from Studio. I am running the package from the tray.

Things I did to solve the issue by myself:

Removed extension and installed again (multiple times).
Cleared browsing data before execution.
Update the package few times.
Restarted my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear whether you have installed the extension from the Chrome web store, but it is preferable to install the extension using the following command:

```
C:\Program Files\UiPath\Studio\UiPath\SetupExtensions.exe /chrome
```

This will work without having Studio installed. Also bear in mind that if you are launching Chrome in Incognito, you will need to explicitly allow the extension in Incognito by going to the following URL in Chrome:

```
chrome://extensions/
```

Choose "Details" on the UiPath extension, and "Allow in Incognito".

Further information can be found here: [Extension for Chrome](https://docs.uipath.com/studio/docs/extension-for-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
1 Use the StartProcess to start Internet explorer exe file from program files.
2 Send Url as argument eg “www.abc.com”
3 Use on element appear to check if the home page is loaded.
4 Attach browser and use the browser variable to pass to other workflows.
```